# How to check if page is published

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

to check if page is published using server side code i should use this snippet:

```
PublishingPageCollection pages = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web).GetPublishingPages();
    foreach (PublishingPage page in pages)
    {
        if(!page.ListItem.File.Level == SPFileLevel.Published)
    return;

    // logic
    }
```

How could i do the same but using Javascript in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SP.Publishing.PublishingWeb Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj954507.aspx) the method `GetPublishingPages` is not supported in JSOM API.

But you could consider the following example to determine whether page is published or not using JSOM API

```
function getPublishingPages(success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
    var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
    ctx.load(items,'Include(File)');

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        success(items);
    },
    error);
}



SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    getPublishingPages(printPagesInfo,logError);    
});    


function printPagesInfo(pages)
{
   pages.get_data().forEach(function(item){
       var file = item.get_file();
       var pageStatus = file.get_level() === SP.FileLevel.published ? 'published' : 'not published';
       console.log(String.format('Page {0} is {1}', file.get_name(),pageStatus)); 
   });
}


function logError(sender,args){
   console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Why are geting the list? Pages? its the list of pages? i Get Unable to get property 'Deferred' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Publishing pages are stored in Pages **list**.  The Deferred object is a part of jQuery library, it was introduced in jQuery 1.5. Modified the example to remove dependency to jQuery lib

Comment: Alright, i still have Deferred' of undefined or null reference i have my code in page layout

Comment: Could you try the updated answer once again? In prevous one there were still some references to Deferred object

Comment: yeah thanks it works, i have one more question i want to enable major versioning also,  i want to enable versioning when a page is published and then increase?